# Get file extension from undefined file python

Tags: python, graphene-django

Hello every body I need to get the one file extension form binary that's not have name and not extension but can be a ("word", "pdf", "xls"), because  the api  graphql can receive a list of file but the uploader of api not pas the file name oly the binary  and a need  identificate the file and order for save on different servers by file category.

I use

```
from graphene_file_upload.scalars import
```

to upload files in the api

and use the next code for get the extension the file

```
def get_file_extension(self, file):
        extension = file[0:3].hex()
        extencions = {'255044':".pdf", '504b03':".docx", 'd0cf11':".xlsx"}
        result = extencions.get(extension, None)
        if result:
            return result
```

but I have a problem because when pass a file xlsx return docx and is only with Microsoft extensions the problem, some knows what happens??

Comment: Consider using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: @dawg What method do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you need to segrate the files as per the file formats and load/save them separately?

If the file formats you are using are .pdf, .docx, .xlsx, I'd proceed maybe something like this:

```
import pathlib

file_path = '../some_folder'  # some_folder consisting all your files

files = []
with pathlib.Path(file_path) as path:
    pdf_files = sorted(path.glob('*.pdf'))
    docx_files = sorted(path.glob('*.docx'))
    xlsx_files = sorted(path.glob('*.xlsx'))
```

You can use these results `pdf_files`, `docx_files` and `xlsx_files` and use `numpy.load()` or `numpy.save()` or some other operations that would save these results in the format that you want. I hope this is what you are looking for.